# Using a Private Property directly vs using Get and Let/Set

Tags: class, vba, oop, properties, private

Beginner VBA programmer here (and beginner to programming in general) looking to learn more about how effective OOP is done.

Can someone explain or provide a reference discussing the benefits/purpose of using - INSIDE of a class module - `Private Property Get` and/or `Let`/`Set` statements in VBA vs accessing properties directly although no manipulation is required of the data?

Example:

I have created a `cDimension` class (in Excel). This class draws lines as `Shape` objects, and a few other things that are not relevant. The `DrawingScale` variable allows the entire drawing to be scaled as desired. Some of the properties require manipulation when Getting/Setting, others don't.

So, for example, `pWidth` needs to be scaled going in:

```
'clsDimension
Private pWidth As Single    
Private Property Get Width() As Single
    Width = pWidth
End Property
Private Property Let Width(w As Single)
    pWidth = w / DrawingScale
End Property
```

But `pColor` does not require any manipulation, in or out:

```
Private pColor As Integer
Private Property Get Color() As Integer
    Color = pColor
End Property
Private Property Let Color(c As Integer)
    pColor = c
End Property
```

The pWidth property is an instance where using the Private Property Get and Let methods for procedures inside of the class itself makes sense to me. However, my question is: is there any reason to also use Private Property methods to Get and Let/Set the pColor property as well, as I have given them above?

```
Public Function Line(sht As Worksheet, L As tLine, Optional c = vbBlack) As Shape
    Width = DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(L.first.x, L.first.y, _
                                     L.second.x, L.second.y) '<-- pWidth is scaled
    Color = c '<-- Vs. just using pColor = c
    Set Line = sht.Shapes.AddLine(L.first.x, L.first.y, L.second.x, L.second.y)
End Function
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code maintenance and evolution means that "Does not require any maniplation" doesn't always end up as "will never require...", so it's considered good practice to "always" use the property Let/Get, *even within the class*, rather than work directly with the private backing field.

Comment: Simple answer, but I guess that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I've worked with someone who declared all of their class module variables as public rather than private so they could be used without get and let, and it was always weird to me.  I typically think of a class module as performing certain actions and not just being used as a data type, so I generally use get and let and perform some data validation on anything incomming to restrict and control what shows up in my class.  It's one of the advantages if you ask me, but I'm not sure how you'd describe that in the coding paradigms out there.

Comment: Your syntax is actually not quite right there, you might want to edit it to include the Property key word. The code as written will not compile.

Comment: Thanks. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not manipulating the values on the way in or way out, just use public variables.  VBA is more like Python than Java or C++ in that **there is no real penalty for switching from public variables to "getter/setter" functions down the road**.

Let's say you start with the following code:

```
'clsCar
Public Speed As Double
Public Sub Drive()
    MsgBox "Driving at " & Speed & " MPH"
End Sub    


'Module1
Sub DriveCar()
    Set Car = New clsCar
    Car.Speed = 100
    Car.Drive  'shows msg:  "Driving at 100 MPH"
End Sub
```

Then you decide that driving that fast is dangerous, so you want to add a "governor" to your vehicle and need to update your class:

```
'clsCar
Private mSpeed As Double
Private Const SpeedLimit As Double = 55

Public Property Get Speed()
    Speed = mSpeed
End Property
Public Property Let Speed(Val As Double)
    If Val > SpeedLimit Then
        mSpeed = SpeedLimit
    ElseIf Val < 0 Then
        mSpeed = 0
    Else
        mSpeed = Val
    End If
End Property
Public Sub Drive()
    MsgBox "Driving at " & Speed & " MPH"
End Sub    


'Module1
'Note that no changes to this code are necessary; the change
'   is entirely encapsulated within the class (as it should be)
Sub DriveCar()
    Set Car = New clsCar
    Car.Speed = 100
    Car.Drive  'shows msg:  "Driving at 55 MPH"
End Sub
```

Tim Williams's comment is what you will often hear as justification for unnecessarily using Get/Let/Set in VBA, but that's the byproduct of good advice from other languages (C++ and Java, notably) being misapplied to VBA/VB6.

Answer (score 1):

As always.... it depends. Your x property should definitely be accessed via the letter because the letter performs a calculation on the input.

```
'clsDimension
Private Let Width(w As Single)
    pWidth = w / DrawingScale
End Property
```

You should **NOT** access the `pWidth` variable directly. If you did, you would have to duplicate the `pWidth = w / DrawingScale` logic elsewhere in your module.

Your `pColor` property *could* be a public variable, because there's no logic in getting or setting it. I don't recommend it though. What if later you realize you don't want to allow certain colors? Then you would need logic behind it and you would need to switch to a property anyway. The property is easier to maintain and more semantically correct.

Answer (score 1):

The value I see is reduced code, which you are not taking advantage of in your sample code. You could replace this:

```
'clsDimension
Private pWidth As Single    
Private Property Get Width() As Single
    Width = pWidth
End Property
Private Property Let Width(w As Single)
    pWidth = w / DrawingScale
End Property
```

with this:

```
'clsDimension
Private Property Get Width() As Single
    Width = w / DrawingScale
End Property
```

This eliminates the potential ambiguity of accessing pWidth or the width property since pWidth no longer exists. It also eliminates the potential pitfall of Width being read before it has been written, although it would be wise to add a bit of code that checks that w and DrawingScale have been set to valid values before you read Width.